# OS X RDP server application

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I am searching for a RDP implementation on OS X, but can't find any.

Does OS X have an RDP implementation application?

Comment: RDP is a technology to solve the problem of allowing remote access. Are you looking for an RDP implementation or more generally for a way to remotely access your Mac?

Comment: I am specifically looking for a RDP implementation :) @patrix

Comment: Are you looking for a server (so you can connect to OS X from e.g. a Windows system) or a client (to connect to a Windows system from OS X)?

Comment: This has not aged well. Please ask on [meta] for help if you want to reopen this or if it’s better to ask a new question explaining what RDP success looks like. Let’s leave this frozen as a snapshot of what Mac hosting and rental services looked like for a couple of years around 2014.

Answer (score 7):

I, too, was a loyal user of iRAPP. CodeRebel is still in bankruptcy as of today. There's a new company, https://www.nuords.com/, that the CTO of CodeRebel has co-founded to sell comparable technology. I have not tested this product; I don't know whether the IP issues have been resolved.

xrdp works on Sierra (I'm using it right now). The compilation instructions can be found on these two pages:

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/wiki/Building-on-OSX-(not-official)
https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp/issues/78

The instructions work with macports as well as homebrew; on macports, the final package you need is pkgconfig rather than pkg-config, and you don't have to work around the absence of OpenSSL. It took me about 15 minutes from start to finish to get it running.

Comment: Has anyone had their company or lawyer clear NuoRDS ? It seems highly likely to get shut down for selling commercial access against the EULA for macOS. http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1012.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I believe iRAPP from CodeRebel may fit the bill http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp

Comment: the demo shows an iRAP client on windows machine , so it means a iRAPP rdp server will be installed on mac and that can be access through any of rdp client or through iRAP client only @Scott Walter

Comment: CodeRebel are in Administration having declared Bankruptcy and their licensing servers are offline: http://www.coderebel.com/about/news/2016/06/06/stop-operations-20160605

Comment: I'm amazed that they can still afford to keep a web site up despite being bankrupt... wouldn't regular expenses be one of the first things you stop paying? o_o

Comment: The way bankruptcy works is that a judge decides which expenses get paid, or appoints a receiver to decide.  The goal is to preserve as much value as possible for the creditors, which sometimes requires spending a bit of money so things don't rot/decay/etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but give [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) a look - bet that iRAPP will be your best option.

Comment: xrdp is for linux base system only right..??
Correct me if I am wrong ..

Comment: Issues with xrdp prevent it working on OS X currently: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues

Answer (score 2):

There is one, called XRDP.
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-control-your-mac-using-win-rdp-client-xrdp-compiling-guide-on-osx.1770325/​​​

Answer (score 1):

I was a licensed iRAPP user, but yesterday the application started saying License was Expired.

I installed the OSXxRDP bridge and it serves up an Xrdp service to the native OSX VNC server. So I connect to OSX using the native built-in RDP client from Win7

My old RDP shortcut connects to it and even autoscaling still works.. which is nice for resizing the Window when the OSX resolution is set high and I want to shrink it down to a smaller window on my desktop. Best of both worlds. It doesn't forward audio.. and its not multichannel, so no services like remote print to printers on the Mac.. but serves the purpose of avoiding installing a VNC client on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I have nothing against OSXxRDP, but I'm truly amazed how you guys are pushing untrue information about iRAPP. Yes, CodeRebel went down, but their licensing servers were taken over by developers and they were supporting iRAPP for free. There was not any down time. Also, If your license is not a trial, it can not expire. Only support subscription could expire, which is not a problem for the installed version. Just saying, be honest in competition. By the way, there is a new product https://www.nuords.com/

Comment: Instead of talking about other products can you add some details about the product you are recommending instead?

Comment: NuoRDS got some coverage by a Mac collocation company recently. It’s hard to see how their paid licensing model is compatible with the macOS EULA which seems to have language strictly forbidding remote time sharing. “only one user may use the Apple Software at a time” from http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1012.pdf

Comment: I guess there is a some misconception. This is not a software producer, who is responsible for compliance with Apple's EULA. When you are buying a gun, everybody knows you can blow up somebody's head, but you are the one who will be responsible.  If you want to comply with EULA in multi-user mode, install TS on macOS Server.

Comment: iRapp's licensing server was definitely down for a long time.  I had to purchase alternative software.  I'm using Remotix.  It's not quite as good as iRapp was in speed and copy/paste sometimes breaks.