# Windows Remote Desktop Connection to Mac

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, vmware

I've Mac OS X (El Capitan) VMs in ESXi 6 on our local network that I can SSH into and I can VNC into and I can connect Xamarin Mac Agent to but I *can't* Remote Desktop Connection (Windows 10) into. Our developers are all on Windows but need access to the Mac VMs for cross-platform development, particularly viewing the iOS Simulator.

How do you set up a vanilla Mac OS X install to enable remoting into it with Windows Remote Desktop Connection?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's simply not possible with MS RDC, only Win>Win or Mac>Win.

Comment: I was able to use RDC to connect to a macincloud instance I rented last week.

Comment: There are RDP servers for Mac: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125792/os-x-rdp-server-application

Answer (score 1):

**It's your virtualization software that provides the RDP server, not OS X itself.**

I don't know what you are using specifically, so I will frame my answer using VirtualBox as the example.  However, the principle is basically the same.

On my FreeBSD VM that I have running on my iMac (10.11.5), I have the option to turn on *Remote Display* as well as configure which port it connects to as well as how I authenticate to the display server.

[image]

In this case, VirtualBox uses the RDP protocol, so you can have any RDP client, whether it's Windows or OS X or even Linux connect to this particular VM.

There is nothing that I have to do to the OS *running* in the VM instance to connect.  Infact, the connection will remain persistent across reboots so you can in fact issue a `shutdown -r now` command and watch it go through the whole process.

Comment: I've updated my question to show that we're using ESXi 6, thanks.

Comment: It's been a looooog time since I have used VMWare - we switched to the MS Hypervisor because we were a mostly MS shop for the server.  From what I remember, we connected the RDP client through VM View, but you will have to get your documentation for ESXi6